# lyx problem: ps, pdf "Authors not shown"

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm trying to write a paper based on VLDB .cls and .tex files, it can be reached from [here](http://www.vldb2010.org/ppp.htm).It uses ACM SIG Proceedings Style.After fixing many errors, now i don't get any errors, However when i save my file as pdf or ps,i can not see the author names.

The title and abstract are shown just not the code between these is not shown.

i'm using lyx on Ubuntu.

Here is the code for the authors.

```
% ****************** TITLE ****************************************

\title{A Sample {\ttlit VLDB} Proceedings Paper in LaTeX
Format\titlenote{for use with vldb.cls}}
\subtitle{[Extended Abstract]
\titlenote{A full version of this paper is available as\textit{Author's Guide to Preparing ACM SIG Proceedings Using \LaTeX$2_\epsilon$\ and BibTeX} at \texttt{www.acm.org/eaddress.htm}}}

% ****************** AUTHORS **************************************

% You need the command \numberofauthors to handle the 'placement
% and alignment' of the authors beneath the title.
%
% For aesthetic reasons, we recommend 'three authors at a time'
% i.e. three 'name/affiliation blocks' be placed beneath the title.
%
% NOTE: You are NOT restricted in how many 'rows' of
% "name/affiliations" may appear. We just ask that you restrict
% the number of 'columns' to three.
%
% Because of the available 'opening page real-estate'
% we ask you to refrain from putting more than six authors
% (two rows with three columns) beneath the article title.
% More than six makes the first-page appear very cluttered indeed.
%
% Use the \alignauthor commands to handle the names
% and affiliations for an 'aesthetic maximum' of six authors.
% Add names, affiliations, addresses for
% the seventh etc. author(s) as the argument for the
% \additionalauthors command.
% These 'additional authors' will be output/set for you
% without further effort on your part as the last section in
% the body of your article BEFORE References or any Appendices.

\numberofauthors{8} %  in this sample file, there are a *total*
% of EIGHT authors. SIX appear on the 'first-page' (for formatting
% reasons) and the remaining two appear in the \additionalauthors section.

\author{
% You can go ahead and credit any number of authors here,
% e.g. one 'row of three' or two rows (consisting of one row of three
% and a second row of one, two or three).
%
% The command \alignauthor (no curly braces needed) should
% precede each author name, affiliation/snail-mail address and
% e-mail address. Additionally, tag each line of
% affiliation/address with \affaddr, and tag the
% e-mail address with \email.
%
% 1st. author
\alignauthor
Ben Trovato\titlenote{Dr.~Trovato insisted his name be first.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{1932 Wallamaloo Lane}\\
       \affaddr{Wallamaloo, New Zealand}\\
       \email{trovato@corporation.com}
% 2nd. author
\alignauthor
G.K.M. Tobin\titlenote{The secretary disavows
any knowledge of this author's actions.}\\
       \affaddr{Institute for Clarity in Documentation}\\
       \affaddr{P.O. Box 1212}\\
       \affaddr{Dublin, Ohio 43017-6221}\\
       \email{webmaster@marysville-ohio.com}
% 3rd. author
\alignauthor Lars Th{\Large{\sf{\o}}}rv{$\ddot{\mbox{a}}$}ld\titlenote{This author is the
one who did all the really hard work.}\\
       \affaddr{The Th{\large{\sf{\o}}}rv{$\ddot{\mbox{a}}$}ld Group}\\
       \affaddr{1 Th{\large{\sf{\o}}}rv{$\ddot{\mbox{a}}$}ld Circle}\\
       \affaddr{Hekla, Iceland}\\
       \email{larst@affiliation.org}
\and  % use '\and' if you need 'another row' of author names
% 4th. author
\alignauthor Lawrence P. Leipuner\\
       \affaddr{Brookhaven Laboratories}\\
       \affaddr{Brookhaven National Lab}\\
       \affaddr{P.O. Box 5000}\\
       \email{lleipuner@researchlabs.org}
% 5th. author
\alignauthor Sean Fogarty\\
       \affaddr{NASA Ames Research Center}\\
       \affaddr{Moffett Field}\\
       \affaddr{California 94035}\\
       \email{fogartys@amesres.org}
% 6th. author
\alignauthor Charles Palmer\\
       \affaddr{Palmer Research Laboratories}\\
       \affaddr{8600 Datapoint Drive}\\
       \affaddr{San Antonio, Texas 78229}\\
       \email{cpalmer@prl.com}
}
% There's nothing stopping you putting the seventh, eighth, etc.
% author on the opening page (as the 'third row') but we ask,
% for aesthetic reasons that you place these 'additional authors'
% in the \additional authors block, viz.
\additionalauthors{Additional authors: John Smith (The Th{\o}rv\"{a}ld Group,
email: {\texttt{jsmith@affiliation.org}}) and Julius P.~Kumquat
(The Kumquat Consortium, email: {\texttt{jpkumquat@consortium.net}}).}
\date{30 July 1999}
% Just remember to make sure that the TOTAL number of authors
% is the number that will appear on the first page PLUS the
% number that will appear in the \additionalauthors section.


\maketitle
```

i also tried another author format and still author names not shown.

```
% ****************** TITLE ****************************************

\title{Alternate {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX
Format\titlenote{(Produces...}}

\numberofauthors{3}
% Three authors sharing the same affiliation.
    \author{
      \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
%
      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science }  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }
          }
%
\maketitle
```

also when i checked the title i see that:

```
Error in latexParagraphs: You should not mix title layouts with normal ones.
```

however i see my the document as dvi,ps or pdf

i'm not sure what causes the problem?

EDIT

WHILE converting from .lyx to pdf or dvi i still don't see the authors however, by using shell commands everthing is fine.
i think this is a problem of lyx,
i spend 8 hours to solve it, seriously i set up windows 7 lyx and tried there, still same.

thanks lyx:) You are good when you are working properly.

Comment: +1 for being the 1000th latex question ;)

Comment: I had a similar problem of the authors not showing. Even though I had no LaTeX errors when compiling. For me, just moving the whole authors TeX code to the preamble worked fine, now the authors are compiled and shown. Title and date are still in the doc, the switched order (title <-> authors) doesn't cause any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vldb.cls` class from the link you mention does not define a command called `\sharedaffiliation`. Commenting out that code allows the file to compile and also see the author names:

```
\documentclass{vldb}
\title{Alternate {\ttlit ACM} SIG Proceedings Paper in LaTeX
Format\titlenote{(Produces...}}
\numberofauthors{3}
    \author{
      \alignauthor Ben King\\      
      \email{king@cs.berkeley.edu}
      \alignauthor Georgia Tobin\\     
      \email{tobin@cs.berkeley.edu}
      \alignauthor Gerald Murray\\    
      \email{murrray@cs.berkeley.edu}
%      \sharedaffiliation
      \affaddr{Department of Electrical Engineering and Computer Science }  \\
      \affaddr{University of California, Berkeley }   \\
      \affaddr{Berkeley, CA 94720-1776 }
    }
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The address is ugly this way, though. It is up to the journal to define how to display author addresses with a single affiliation. Unfortunately, the sample file does not do this. In that situation I would contact the editor and ask.

Comment: @user8472, it was something 0400am and afte waiting 10 min i have to sleep. thanks for the answer. By the way the vldb provides the first code for the authors the other (second) one is get from acm web page. So i have not still solved the problem.

Comment: The page you have linked to (ACM) provides the download of the `vldb.cls` class file for LaTeX. This file does not define a command `\sharedaffiliation` (not even something similar to it). Is it possible that there are different versions of the class file around or that the code you are referring to (the "second one") refers to another `.cls` file?

Comment: Regarding the issue with the ugly formatting of the affiliations below the author names I get the impression that the journal wants the affiliation to be repeated below every author, even if they have the same affiliation. But this is not really a technical question, rather a stylistic one (and thus the responsibility of the journal).

Comment: Sorry about missing the Lyx part, I just focused on the LaTeX side. Are you sure that Lyx uses the correct class file `vldb.cls`? Does the output look like the output from raw LaTeX (including the copyright notice and the fonts etc.)?

Comment: Just for clarification: Lyx needs to be configured to use the correct class file; there is documentation on how to do that here: http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts If you cannot see the things I pointed out above (copyright notice, the same custom fonts etc.) it is a sign that Lyx did not pick the correct class file!

Comment: @user8472, if use @username i can be notified. Thank for the answers, sure uses, as i said in my edit part when i'm using lyx to convert ps or pdf i'm getting this error, in shell prompt everything is fine:)